# Mapbox/leaflet.js change color of marker on hover

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, leaflet, mapbox

UPDATE: I have found that when I am setting the geojson, it is creating the new set of markers and immediately triggering the mouseover event. It infinitely loops it and breaks it. I changed it to click and it works, so how can I make this work with hover now?

I am loading festivals onto my map on the right side to for my festival index page. This is similar functionality to yelp's index page. So I have successfully loaded the data as geoJSON to my markerLayer, but when I set the geojson of the data to change the color of the marker that is being hovered, it disables the 'click' and 'mouseout' events. There are a lot of ways to order this code, and I have tried a lot with moving stuff out of the ajax call but I can't seem to get it working.

Why won't this code work? And what can I do to make it work? I know it has to do with my lack of understanding of layers, mapbox, and setting geojson.

I also wanted to know if there is a better solution to my problem like maybe using font awesome and changing the font color instead. All feedback is welcome!

[image: Festival Index]

```
map = L.mapbox.map("index-map", "jbhatab.map-iu8zewt3")
    markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer()
    $.ajax
      dataType: 'text'
      url: 'festivals.json'
      success: (data) ->
        geojson = $.parseJSON(data)
        markerLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson)
        console.log markerLayer

        $(".event-list-item").hover (->
          $(this).addClass "hover"
          console.log $(this).data('festival-id')
        ), ->
          $(this).removeClass "hover"

        markerLayer.on "mouseover", (e) ->
          e.layer.feature.properties['old-color'] = e.layer.feature.properties['marker-color']
          e.layer.feature.properties['marker-color'] = '#000'
          e.layer.openPopup()
          markerLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson)
          console.log e.target
          console.log 'mousover'

        markerLayer.on "mouseout", (e) ->
          console.log 'mouseout'

        markerLayer.on "click", (e) ->
          console.log 'click'
          e.layer.unbindPopup()
          window.open '/festivals/' + e.layer.feature.properties.id

        markerLayer.addTo(map)
        map.fitBounds markerLayer.getBounds()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify a marker on hover, use the `layer` attribute of the event object and use `setIcon` to set a new icon for that layer: the `setGeoJSON` function should not be used in cases where it can cause a loop like this one.